# Does updating BIOS solve certain BSODs?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, bsod, updates

Specifically speaking I am wanting to update my BIOS for my P8Z77 Asus M-PRO motherboard. I'm running a ivy bridge i7 3770k with a GTX 570, 2 X 8GB G.Skill 1333 DDR3 RAM
I have the latest driver installed for my graphics card but I don't know what else might need to be updated.

The reason for updating BIOS is because I keep getting BSODs that are either MEMORY_MANAGEMENT or PFN_LIST_CORRUPT are the ones I see every so often and they come irregularly but every so often... (Could be days back to back, or 10 minutes within each BSOD or a month in and nothing and then all of a sudden BSOD) But I don't know if that's memory related or motherboard related or something else entirely.

I noticed updates for my motherboard on the ASUS site for the BIOS. I've never updated a BIOS before and did some digging and I don't want to brick my mobo or destroy it due to a wrong update in the midst of a schoolterm. 
I'm unsure of if I should just rename the file and put it in a USB and do it with the easy USB BIOS flashback feature the motherboard suggests on its features. Has anyone tried this??
It's just losing work here and there is very time consuming to recreate what I lose due to the BSODs even if it is a few minutes of work lost (I save a lot).

And As I just tried to Post this question my google chrome has that folder with the crash face on it a lot randomly and that seems to happen quite a bit too when it "feels" like it's going to go into a BSOD soon of either PFN_LIST_CORRUPT or MEMORY_MANAGEMENT

Comment: Sounds like possible bad memory to me.  Make sure your RAM is okay ([ensure it passes Memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) a few times), and in this case, I doubt a BIOS update would do anything (if not for anything else than the BSOD error messages you wrote - why would a BIOS update change how a motherboard handled memory management?).

Comment: [This](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/568-63-bsod-pfn_list_corrupt) page might help.

Comment: Intel chipsets are picky about memory, suspect a memory module issue or a misbehaving driver.